# Why did Anissa's powers and Jennifer's emerge at roughly the same time?

Tags: dc, black-lightning-2018

If I recall correctly, Anissa's powers mainly start showing up in the first season, whereas those of Jennifer emerge more in the second season. However, the impression that I got was that the emergence of their powers was a normal part of growing up, as it were. That was why they had not had any abilities previously, for instance. Other dialogue in the show supports this idea.

However, in that case, why did their powers start developing at the almost the same time, despite a sizeable age difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a direct textual support for either of these hypotheses, but I think they are at least textually consistent:

**1  Jennifer and Anissa could have developed their powers at the same age, but Anissa didn't notice until later.**

The default state of Jennifer's powers is very obvious. Without even trying she can glow and when she totally loses control she can become incorporeal. By contrast, Anissa needs to breathe in a certain way and hit something or be shot. If she's not actively pushing on something, there's no obvious sign of her powers. Perhaps she had simply never stumbled on the correct breathing before.

**2. Age may not be enough. They may need to encounter some sort of trama after reaching a certain age to activate their powers.**

This hypothesis is supported in that many of the people in the show who develop powers seem to encounter some trama shortly before finding out about them. The girls are kidnapped, Jefferson saw his father murdered, and the NSA inflicts painful experiments on people to test their powers.

Of the two, I think the first hypothesis is more likely. In episode 1 we hear that Anissa was involved in a protests against the 100 that turned violent and led to her arrest. If trama were all that was needed to unlock her powers, a violent protest seems like it would have been enough to activate them.